# html to PDF issue in Avery 8160 labels

Tags: html, css, pdf, pdf-generation, dompdf

I am facing an issue to generate HTML to PDF using DomPDF. I have to print labels on page Avery 8160 labels. In that when I generate and view pdf it doesn't take proper CSS. And that's why printing data in not look proper in Avery 8160 page formate.

Please, guys, help me. What I have to do.

Is there any solution?

Thanks in advance.

Avery 8160 Lable Template:- https://www.avery.com/templates/8160

Print Image Looks Like- http://prntscr.com/pxaf0d

:(

Comment: Plz guys help. If anyone know about that

Comment: I have put a question 2 days ago . no one reply :((((((

Comment: :( .............................................